# подключение к mysql visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Пытаюсь соединить проект c++ и mysql. Сделал все что указано в инструкции https://kildekode.ru/sandbox/2993/Podklyuchenie-i-rabota-s-MySQL-v-srede-Visual-C.htm Но при компиляции ошибка

> fatal error LNK1181: не удается открыть входной файл "libmysql.lib"

Может кто то сталкивался или есть более удобные способы подключения?

Comment: в папку, куда поставился коннектор, эта библиотека имеется на диске?

Comment: если существует, то проверьте, что в настройках компоновщика в дополнительные каталоги библиотек вы указали ту папку, которая имеет эту библиотеку.